# Downloading VLMC

Tags: video-editor

I have been looking for a video editor, and among the recommended editors is VLMC. However, when I go to the [site](http://www.videolan.org/vlmc/), I can't find anything resembling a download link. Is VLMC still alive? Is there an official place to download the latest version? I have found a few non-official channels, but I am leery of downloading anything that isn't linked from an official page, and they all seem to say something along the lines pre-alpha, if there is any information at all. How can I try this software, or is it a lost cause?

Comment: You must have missed this text which is fairly prominent on the VLMC page: "Note that VLMC is still under development and therefore not ready for beta testing or production yet."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who recommended VLMC to you? It's still in early development, best thing you will get is an unstable developer alpha, nothing close to being usable. It also says so right on their website:

> Note that VLMC is still under development and therefore not ready for beta testing or production yet.

To be honest I don't see this project going anywhere any time soon. It's been around for year, I'm not even sure if it's still actively being worked on, and even if it is, it will be a long time before you can expect a workable beta build.

Just do a websearch for free video editors (though if you are willing to spent some money, there are some good options as well) and you will find plenty of free software. Among the typically recommended ones are [Lightworks](https://www.lwks.com/) (free and paid versions available), [Avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/) (free), [Hitfilm Express](https://hitfilm.com/express) (partially free) and [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) (free open source 3D program with NLE functionality). There's plenty more for all price ranges, up to industrial standard software such as Premiere Pro and Avid Media Composer, you just have to look for something that fits your needs and budget.

Comment: It was recommended in this answer from 2011: http://video.stackexchange.com/a/2301/18342. It seemed odd that something recommended side by side with others in 2011 should still be in alpha. That answer doesn't show any signs of having been edited since, unless I'm just not able to see them or something.

Comment: @Trevortni It would appear that answer was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The project seems to be alive (at least was 3 months ago). There's build instructions in the repository if you want to test it. You can follow and contribute in [GitLab](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlmc/commits/master)